# Angular valuechange not noticed in HTML

Tags: angular, typescript, callback, electron

in my App i have a Callback Function that waits for Electron Data send back to Angular and then show the changes. I can change the Value but it's not noticed in the HTML file. So the wrong Data is shown.

The Function in component.ts:

```
    public async startDefault(): Promise<void> {
        try {
            this.oDefaultLoader.startLoading();
            this.setNewvalues("api", {
                max: 1,
                cur: 0
            });
            setTimeout((): void => {
                this.setNewvalues("api", {
                    max: 19,
                    cur: 5
                });
            }, 6000);
            await this.electron.sendIpcPipe("startDefault", async (oData: IIpcChainResponse): Promise<void> => {
                console.log(oData);
                this.setNewvalues("api", {
                    max: oData.max,
                    cur: oData.cur
                });

            }, this.settings.oSetting);
            this.oDefaultLoader.stopLoading();
        } catch (oErr) {
            this.oDefaultLoader.stopLoading();
            console.log(oErr);
        }
    }

    // Background Actions
    private setNewvalues(sSet: "api" | "bo", oValues: IProgressObject): void {
        this.oDefaultStart = deepMergeObject(this.oDefaultStart, {
            [sSet]: oValues
        } as IDefaultStart);
        console.log(this.oDefaultStart.api);
    }
```

The sendIpcPipe function:

```
    public async sendIpcPipe<T, U>(sEndpoint: string, fnPipe: (data: T) => Promise<void>, oArgs?: U): Promise<void> {
        if (this.electron.isElectronApp) {
            return new Promise<void>((resolve: Function, _reject: Function): void => {
                const oListener: (_event: Electron.IpcRendererEvent, oResponse: T) => Promise<void> = async (
                    _event: Electron.IpcRendererEvent,
                    oResponse: T
                ): Promise<void> => {
                    if (oResponse as unknown as number === 0) {
                        this.electron.ipcRenderer.off(sEndpoint + "Response", oListener);
                        resolve();
                    } else {
                        await fnPipe(oResponse);
                    }
                };
                this.electron.ipcRenderer.on(sEndpoint + "Response", oListener);
                this.electron.ipcRenderer.send(sEndpoint, oArgs);
            });
        }
        return;
    }
```

The HTML code just to show the object:

```
<div>
    {{ oDefaultStart.api | json }}
</div>
```

**Update**

If I use `setNewvalues` outside the callback function of `sendIpcPipe` it's working fine. But outside nothing or only sometimes something changed.

Comment: Look into the ChangeDetector class in Anguar.core lib.  In particular detectChanges method.

Comment: This is not realy helpful. I have no idea if I should with this "tip".

Answer (score 0):

The best way to react on value changes is to use magic of RXJS.

I'd make oDefaultStart as an BehavioralSubject and then use async pipe in HTML.

If you are new to RXJS, check this useful video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ewcoEYS85Co

Comment: I tried this but it changed nothing. Still see the basedata in oDefaultStart